# joint_trajectory_controllers for ROS Melodic on Arch Linux

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosdep, joint-trajectory-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

After a new fresh install of ROS Melodic on our Arch machine, I noticed that upon installing deps for the new **ur_robot_driver**, the package `joint_trajectory_controller` is not available on arch, at least for Melodic. For Kinetic and Indigo, I could find packages in the AUR, but not for Melodic.

Does anyone know how to get this running on Arch ?

Because I would like to not have to switch to an Ubuntu VM just for ROS development.

Cheers

PS: Error message from `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -y`:

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys
resolved to system dependencies:

ur_controllers: No definition of [joint_trajectory_controller] for OS [arch] 

ur_robot_driver: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [ur_msgs]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/352327/joint_trajectory_controllers-for-ros-melodic-on-arch-linux/) by [ramdambo](https://answers.ros.org/users/54911/ramdambo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not being able to install a package using your package manager is one of the valid reasons for building them from source (#q320046: it mentions Ubuntu in the title, but the same reasoning aplies on other OS, see the points in the *No release available* section).

For a description of the general workflow when building packages from source, you could refer to #q252478.

If you really need to build much more from source (because `rosdep` tells you fi it cannot find the dependencies of the packages in `ros_controllers` in your package manager), then you would probably have to resort to `rosinstall_generator`. Before doing that though you may want to contact whoever is maintaining the Arch repositories, as `ros_control` is a pretty common dependency and I would expect it to be available.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ramdambo](https://answers.ros.org/users/54911/ramdambo/) on 2020-05-27**:
Hi there, sorry for the delay.
I tried to install **ros_controllers** from source but as you suspected, I had to install even more depencencies after that, so I resorted to **rosinstall_generator**.

Problem is that even here, I am missing dependencies, namely **libgazebo9-dev**, **libboost-thread-dev** and **libboost-filesystem-dev** even though **boost** and **gazebo** are installed.

I'll try to contact the maintainer/s. I suppose you mean the maintainer of **ros-melodic-desktop-full** right ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-27**:\

> I'll try to contact the maintainer/s. I suppose you mean the maintainer of `ros-melodic-desktop-full` right ?

No.

The people doing the Arch linux packaging.

**Comment by [ramdambo](https://answers.ros.org/users/54911/ramdambo/) on 2020-05-27**:
Yeah that's what I meant, should have been clearer. But apparently an issue addressing the missing dependencies has already been opened.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-27**:
Please link that issue here, so we can keep things connected.